ntptrace always outputs the error message "Invalid association ID specified" at the end
It seems that this "error" should not be at least a bug within the ntptrace program since we have run it under the RHEL 5.x/6.x with the same "error" result.
So my questions are the following:

Why the ntptrace always output the error message at the end?
How to avoid such error messages within the output of the ntptrace?

RHEL 5.8
# ntptrace
localhost.localdomain: stratum 4, offset -0.000126, synch distance 0.324174
172.25.180.129: stratum 3, offset -0.009254, synch distance 0.303356
***Invalid association ID specified

# rpm -qa|grep -i ntp|grep -i \.x86
ntp-4.2.2p1-17.el5_10.x86_64
# 

RHEL 6.4
# ntptrace
localhost: stratum 4, offset -0.000301, synch distance 0.008727
172.25.180.129: stratum 3, offset -0.000798, synch distance 0.297444
***Invalid association ID 176364532 specified

# rpm -qa|grep -i ntp|grep -i \.x86
ntp-perl-4.2.6p5-15.el6_10.x86_64
ntpdate-4.2.6p5-15.el6_10.x86_64
ntp-4.2.6p5-15.el6_10.x86_64


CentOS 7.5
Now I installed and tested the corresponding ntp-perl package on my CentOS 7.5 system (It is a bit regretful that I have no RHEL 7 environment).
This version ntptrace just work normally fine ... !  So it seems that there might be really "a bug" in the lower version of ntp-perl package?
# rpm -ivh /install/ntp-perl-4.2.6p5-28.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
warning: /install/ntp-perl-4.2.6p5-28.el7.centos.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:ntp-perl-4.2.6p5-28.el7.centos   ################################# [100%]

# ntptrace
localhost: stratum 3, offset 0.000532, synch distance 0.000485
192.168.89.5: stratum 2, offset 0.000814, synch distance 0.000443
10.131.122.10: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out


You can't assume you will be able to contact all the upstream servers, all the way to the stratum 0 clock.  Some of them might well be on private networks.  Or, are you asking why a timed-out network request (to a private IP address) gives a invalid association ID on RHEL, but not on CentOS?  Is there a difference between an NTP server with an invalid association ID (since it can't be contacted) and an NTP server that times out (since it can't be contacted)?
